# Conectar con API de IDEALISTA

Tags: api

Soy nuevo en el mundo de la programacion Android.
La duda que tengo a la hora de conectar con la api de Idealista.  La autentificacion es CORRECTA.
Le paso el "`access_token`"  e intento hacer una consulta de la siguiente manera:

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzY29wZSI6WyJyZWFkIl0sImV4cCI6MTU4MTQ3Mjk4NCwiYXV0aG9yaXRpZXMiOlsiUk9MRV9QVUJMSUMiXSwianRpIjoiYTU2OTM2YzEtODljYy00ODQzLTgzZDctODI0MWNlZmE3MGM1IiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoidGc2N3Iwczl6eG5jb3NlZG1vYmhkd2ZkaWdkb2N0em8ifQ.F1U0GvO2Ok4Bp4jqe7_2JmmRB_XT2PHZ0Q8NV6PGuNg" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data;"  -F "center=40.430,-3.702" -F "propertyType=homes" -F "country=es" -F "distance=15000" -F "operation=sale" "https://api.idealista.com/3.5/es/search"
```

Una vez enviado me sale el siguiente error:

```
{"message":"propertyType is required","httpStatus":400}
```

La cosa esta en que el propertyType  ya se lo estoy pasando en el Token.

Si podeis ayudar os lo agradeceria muchismo.

Gracias te antemano

Comment: ¿Tienes un enlace a la documentaciín API de idealista? Lo digo porque facilitaría las cosas para que te puedan dar una respuesta. Yo lo he intentado pero parece que hay que registrarse, ¿sabes si hay un enlace público a la documentación de la API para entrar sin estar registrado?

Comment: Tengo dos pdf, que son los que te dan cuando obtienes la api

Answer (score 0):

elimina el punto y coma (;) del encabezado `Content-Type`:

```
curl -v 'https://api.idealista.com/3.5/es/search' \
         --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
         ...
```